# Error message when trying to get PETSc to draw to an X terminal by passing -mat_view_draw

Tags: petsc, visualization

I've made a matrix, and now I want to draw it on the screen to make a basic check of correctness. The [documentation](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MatAssemblyEnd.html#MatAssemblyEnd) for `MatAssemblyEnd()` states that I can pass an option to do this:

> -mat_view_draw - PetscDraws nonzero structure of matrix, using MatView() and PetscDrawOpenX().

But when I run my program with this option, I get the following error:

```
[0]PETSC ERROR: --------------------- Error Message ------------------------------------
[0]PETSC ERROR: No support for this operation for this object type!
[0]PETSC ERROR: Viewer type draw not supported!
[0]PETSC ERROR: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Does PETSc still support drawing to X terminals? Or is this just an indication of a bug somewhere in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure probably did not find X11. You can check whether it was found using

```
$ grep '\<PETSC_HAVE_X\>' $PETSC_DIR/$PETSC_ARCH/include/petscconf.h 
#ifndef PETSC_HAVE_X
#define PETSC_HAVE_X 1
```

If you don't see `PETSC_HAVE_X` defined, try reconfiguring `--with-x` (perhaps with a path, see `./configure --help` for details on what to specify).

Comment: I don't get `PETSC_HAVE_X`, but I do see `#ifndef PETSC_HAVE_X11

#define PETSC_HAVE_X11 1`. Should that also work?

Comment: Yeah, the macro depends on the version of PETSc. What matrix type are you using?

Comment: I'm using SEQAIJ. And the version of PETSc I'm using is 3.2.

Comment: Send the full error message to petsc-maint@mcs.anl.gov.

Comment: I checked the configuration options, and --with-x isn't in there. I think that's probably the problem.